# My insert node at tail function doesn't change the value of the tail

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, nodes

So i was trying to write a function that takes the head of a linked list and a data as arguments and appends a node at the tail of the linked list. And it seens to work fine (note that the head of the linked list isn't a node initially, it is equal to None actually) when it prints the 'new' head from inside the function (head becomes a node where head.data = 0 and head.next = None), but when i print the linked list's head after calling the function it doesn't return a node, in fact it returns None, meaning that the function didn't inserted the node at the tail which is initially the head. Can someone explain why the head's value isn't changing?

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

def InsertNode(head, data):

    if head == None:
        print("head == None, so head will be a node now")
        head = Node(data)
        print("now, head is a node where head.data = {} and head.next = {}".format(head.data, head.next))

    else: 
        tail = head
        while tail.next != None:
            tail = tail.next
            tail.next = Node(data)

def PrintLL(linkedList):

    node = linkedList.head

    while node != None:
        print (node.data)

    node = node.next

llist = LinkedList()
##print("llist.head == {}".format(llist.head))

InsertNode(llist.head, 0)
print("after InsertNode with data = 0, llist.head == {}".format(llist.head))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the fixed code:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

def InsertNode(node, data):

    if node.head == None:
        print("head == None, so head will be a node now")
        node.head = Node(data)
        print("now, head is a node where head.data = {} and head.next = {}".format(node.head.data, node.head.next))

    else: 
        tail = node.head
        while tail.next != None:
            tail = tail.next
            tail.next = Node(data)

def PrintLL(linkedList):

    node = linkedList.head

    while node != None:
        print (node.data)

    node = node.next

llist = LinkedList()
##print("llist.head == {}".format(llist.head))

InsertNode(llist, 0)
print("after InsertNode with data = 0, llist.head == {}".format(llist.head))
```

What was happening was you were passing in a pointer to the head:

```
InsertNode(llist.head, 0)
```

InsertNode would then assign a new node instance to that variable:

```
head = Node(data)
```

Since the head pointer is passed by assignment, the version of `head` local to the function `InsertNode` was changed, but the original `llist.head` was not affected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `LinkedList` object itself to `InsertNode` instead of its `head` attribute. By passing the `head` attribute to `InsertNode`, any new assignments made to it will not be reflected on the original object.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

def InsertNode(linkedList, data):

    if linkedList.head == None:
        print("head == None, so head will be a node now")
        linkedList.head = Node(data)
        print("now, head is a node where head.data = {} and head.next = {}".format(linkedList.head.data, linkedList.head.next))

    else:
        tail = linkedList.head
        while tail.next != None:
            tail = tail.next
            tail.next = Node(data)

def PrintLL(linkedList):

    node = linkedList.head

    while node != None:
        print (node.data)

    node = node.next

llist = LinkedList()

InsertNode(llist, 0)
print("after InsertNode with data = 0, llist.head == {}".format(llist.head.data))
```

Comment: Yes that helps, but on the original problem it was the head attribute of the linklist that was being passed in the function and i couldn't change this part of the code (don't know why they did that tho)